# Schema requiring less fields than declared

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am running a Spark program transforming a TSV to Parquet.  On my write I am getting an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 5 fields are required while 7 values are provided.`  I am not doing much, just applying field names and applying types before the writing the data.

```
rdd = sc.textFile('s3://in-location/').map(lambda x: x.split('\t'))
df = rdd.toDF()

if "_1" in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("_1", "ts")
else:
    df = df.withColumn("ts", sf.lit(None))

if "_2" in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("_2", "ts_offset")
else:
    df = df.withColumn("ts_offset", sf.lit(None))

if "_3" in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("_3", "id")
else:    
    df = df.withColumn("id", sf.lit(None))   

if "_4" in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("_4", "testing")
else:
   df = df.withColumn("testing", sf.lit(None))

if "_5" in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("_5", "value")
else:
    df = df.withColumn("value", sf.lit(None))

if "_6" in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("_6", "version")
else:
    df = df.withColumn("version", sf.lit(None))

if "_7" in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("_7", "size")
else:
    df = df.withColumn("size", sf.lit(None))


df = df.withColumn("ts", df["ts"].cast(types.TimestampType()))
df = df.withColumn("ts_offset", df["ts_offset"].cast(types.ShortType()))
df = df.withColumn("id", df["id"].cast(types.StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("testing", df["testing"].cast(types.BooleanType()))
df = df.withColumn("value", df["value"].cast(types.StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("version", df["version"].cast(types.StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("size", df["size"].cast(types.StringType()))

outDf = df.select("ts", "ts_offset", "id", "testing", "value", "version", "size")

if "ts" not in outDf.columns:
    outDf = outDf.withColumn("ts", sf.lit(None).cast(types.TimestampType()))

if "ts_offset" not in outDf.columns:
    outDf = outDf.withColumn("ts_offset", sf.lit(None).cast(types.ShortType()))

if "id" not in outDf.columns:
    outDf = outDf.withColumn("id", sf.lit(None).cast(types.StringType()))

if "testing" not in outDf.columns:
    outDf = outDf.withColumn("testing", sf.lit(None).cast(types.BooleanType()))

if "value" not in outDf.columns:
    outDf = outDf.withColumn("value", sf.lit(None).cast(types.StringType()))

if "version" not in outDf.columns:
    outDf = outDf.withColumn("version", sf.lit(None).cast(types.StringType()))

if "size" not in outDf.columns:
    outDf = outDf.withColumn("size", sf.lit(None).cast(types.StringType()))

outDf.printSchema()

outDf\
    .repartition(48)\
    .write.mode("append")\
    .partitionBy("id")\
    .parquet("s3://out-location/")
```

I have been trying to ensure that all columns are present in the final outDf even if all columns are not present in all rows of the input file.  We recently added 2 new columns, so about half of this data is missing those columns.  That is why I am checking and trying to add values of lit(None) if the column isn't present.  I am guessing that there are just certain rows missing the data, which is why it is complaining, but I am unsure on how to fix my problem.  Ideally if data is missing it would be null in the Parquet, how would I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the output location you want to append to only has 5 columns while your dataframe was 7 columns. So you cannot append to this output location. Just try to save to a different location

Comment: I don't believe this is the case.  I tried a different location with the same results,  I believe this is a single run problem, not due to existing data.